# Which Packages do I need to refer to to create my own NUnit console runner?

Tags: c#, .net-core, nunit, nunit-console

I am trying to create my own NUnit console runner.

Adding a reference to `NUnit` to my project does not let me access `NUnit.Common`, `NUnit.Engine` or `NUnit.Options` as used in the console runner in
https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/blob/master/src/NUnitConsole/nunit3-console/Program.cs

My Project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.11.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

My source:

```
using System; 
using NUnit.Common;
using NUnit.Options;
using NUnit.Engine;


namespace MyNUnitRunner
{
    class Program
    {
        static ConsoleOptions Options = new ConsoleOptions(new DefaultOptionsProvider(), new FileSystem());
        private static ExtendedTextWriter _outWriter;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Options.Parse(Options.PreParse(args));
            }
            catch (OptionException ex)
            {
                WriteHeader();
                OutWriter.WriteLine(ColorStyle.Error, string.Format(ex.Message, ex.OptionName));
                return ConsoleRunner.INVALID_ARG;
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

Output of `dotnet build`:

```
Program.cs(2,13): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Common' does not exist in the namespace 'NUnit' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/Users/jon/DEV/CSSandbox/MyNUnitRunner/MyNUnitRunner.csproj]
Program.cs(3,13): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Options' does not exist in the namespace 'NUnit' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/Users/jon/DEV/CSSandbox/MyNUnitRunner/MyNUnitRunner.csproj]
Program.cs(4,13): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Engine' does not exist in the namespace 'NUnit' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/Users/jon/DEV/CSSandbox/MyNUnitRunner/MyNUnitRunner.csproj]
Program.cs(11,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ConsoleOptions' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/jon/DEV/CSSandbox/MyNUnitRunner/MyNUnitRunner.csproj]
Program.cs(12,24): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ExtendedTextWriter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/jon/DEV/CSSandbox/MyNUnitRunner/MyNUnitRunner.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    5 Error(s)
```

Which packages do I need to refer to and how can I find this out (New to C#)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're after the NUnit Engine - this is the part of the project which is intended to be used by external 'runner' programs, to run tests.

You should pull in the `nunit.engine` NuGet package. The only assembly your runner should reference should be `nunit.engine.api.dll` - that's the supported interface which will mean that your runner will continue to work with future versions of the engine.

There's some documentation around the process here: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Test-Engine-API

Your runner should *not* be referencing the `NUnit` NuGet package. That package contains the test framework, which should be referenced by every test assembly, but not by runners.

Hope that helps - good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at project file in GitHub sources, which you've attached. They reference `nunit.engine.api` project, so you should add this as well. [NUnit.Engine.Api](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit.Engine.Api/) is a Nuget package of this reference

Comment: Which project file? I see a reference to an existing project in nunit-console/src/NUnitConsole/nunit3-console/nunit3-console.csproj but not a PackageReference.

Comment: @jbcoe Yes, that's right. They refer their own sources, you should refer packages for your runner, `nunit.engine` and `nunit.engine.api`